# itext pdf with list of image and text below

Tags: pdf, itext

Need help to generate a pdf with a list of image and text describing the image under it.

Tried the below, but getting image and text beside each other. Please need help with this. Thanks.

```
........

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
table.setSplitRows(true);
table.setWidthPercentage(90f);

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
for (int counter = 0; counter < empSize; counter++) { 
    String imgPath = ... ".png");
    Image img = Image.getInstance(imgPath);
    img.scaleAbsolute(110f, 95f);

    Paragraph textParagraph = new Paragraph("Test" + counter));
    textParagraph.setLeading(Math.max(img.getScaledHeight(), img.getScaledHeight()));
    textParagraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

        Phrase imageTextCollectionPhase = new Phrase();
    Phrase ph = new Phrase();
    ph.add(new Chunk(img, 0, 0, true));
        ph.add(textParagraph);  

    imageTextCollectionPhase.add(ph);
    paragraph.add(imageTextCollectionPhase);
}

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(paragraph);
table.addCell(cell);
doc.add(table);
```

Comment: Why are you adding all your content to a single cell? What's the point of creating a table if you only use ine cell? Add your imaged and text to *separate* cells.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you want to get a result that looks like this:

[image]

In your case, you are adding all the content (all the images and all the text) to a single cell. You should add them to separate cells as is done in the [MultipleImagesInTable](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/adding-images-table#1566-multipleimagesintable.java) example:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Image img1 = Image.getInstance(IMG1);
    Image img2 = Image.getInstance(IMG2);
    Image img3 = Image.getInstance(IMG3);
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.setWidthPercentage(20);
    table.addCell(img1);
    table.addCell("Brazil");
    table.addCell(img2);
    table.addCell("Dog");
    table.addCell(img3);
    table.addCell("Fox");
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

You can easily change this proof of concept so that a loop is used. Just make sure you put the `addCell()` methods *inside* the loop instead of *outside* the loop.

You can also explicitly create a `PdfPCell` and combine the text and the image in the same cell like this:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.addElement(img1);
cell.addElement(new Paragraph("Brazil"));
table.addCell(cell);
```

Comment: I never seen any one so much dedicated for his project , every itextsharp question have your answer. thanks a lot as all answers helping me a lot .